# What does the arrow on the bottom left of the folder icon mean?

Tags: macos, finder, mysql

[image: Finder window]

As you see the `mysql` and `mysql-5.7.17-macos10.12-x86_64` under the local path.
The `mysql` folder icon has a arrow on the bottom left.

Does the arrow mean shortcut to the `mysql-5.7.17-macos10.12-x86_64`? Or if not, if it is a other mysql entity folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arrow means it is an alias or link, but it could lead anywhere. To find the destination, select the alias and press ⌘I (or right-click and choose Get Info), then look at the ‘Original’ path (or just open it and see where it leads).

[image]